bear in WSL2 but failed: wrapper: failed with: gRPC call failed: failed to connect to all addresses
Thank you for taking the time to look at my question!
Environment:
OS: WSL2 on Windows11, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
Bear version: 3.0.18, Bear install method: apt
Description:
I am trying bear to generate compile_commands.json for a C project but failed.
> bear -- make
wrapper: failed with: gRPC call failed: failed to connect to all addresses

And, it still generates an empty compile_commands.json.
> make
gcc -Wall -Iinclude src/main.c -o main
> tree
.
├── Makefile
├── compile_commands.json
├── include
│   └── inc.h
├── main
└── src
    └── main.c

I've tried wiki/Troubleshooting on GitHub
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
export GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native
unset https_proxy; unset http_proxy

verbose(too long so I truncate here):
[22:06:05.597561, wr, 1386, ppid: 1381] wrapper: 3.0.18
...
[22:06:05.598583, wr, 1386, ppid: 1381] gRPC call requested: supervise::Supervisor::Resolve
[22:06:25.599308, wr, 1386, ppid: 1381] gRPC call [Resolve] finished: false
[22:06:25.599526, wr, 1386, ppid: 1381] failed with: gRPC call failed: failed to connect to all addresses

export no_proxy=127.0.0.1

And those didn't work.
verbose here:
I appreciate any guidance or insight the community can provide. Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Update:
I modified the .wslconfig file by uncommenting the following line(networkingMode), and everything started working properly. Could anyone explain why this change resolved the issue?
.wslconfig
[experimental]
autoMemoryReclaim=gradual 
# networkingMode=mirrored 
dnsTunneling=true 
firewall=true 
autoProxy=true 
sparseVhd=true 


Update:
strace -e trace=network bear -- gcc hi.c -o hi
wrapper: failed with: gRPC call failed: failed to connect to all addresses
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1205, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1217, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=1} ---
+++ exited with 1 +++


On linux I would run that command with strace to see what it is trying to connect to.  I don't understand why bear would need network access at all.

https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear/issues/415 looks helpful

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

@AllanWind Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for sharing the link! I tried the solution mentioned there, but unfortunately, it didn't have the desired effect.
Regarding strace, as I'm new to Linux, I attempted running strace -e trace=network bear -- gcc hi.c -o hi, which produced two lines of output. However, I'm not sure how to interpret them, so I updated the probelm. I suspect this might be related to gRPC.
Any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated! Best regards.

@tripleee Thank you for the feedback. I understand the importance of including all necessary information within the question itself. I will revise my question to ensure it contains all the relevant details and avoid relying on external links or additional comments.
If you have any specific suggestions on how to improve the clarity of my question or any additional information I should include, please let me know!

I suggest you look at all the output from strace not limit it with -e.  This might tell you what it is trying to connect to.  In any case, you should tag this with wsl2 as that appears to be main relevant part.

Consider filing an issue at https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear/issues if you don't get an answer here. This issue seems specific to bear (only incidentally related to clangd, in that that's the purpose for which you're using bear) and I suspect the set of people knowledgeable about the internals of bear is small and likely found in its issue tracker.

@AllanWind Thank you for your suggestion! I added the WSL tag as you recommended and reviewed the strace output without the -e option. I also passed the logs to GPT, and it confirmed that there were no network connection attempts. Thanks again for your help!

@HighCommander4 Thank you for the advice! I’ve already filed an issue on the Bear GitHub repository.
